# Is it possible to put a function in timed loop using django-background-task

Tags: django, python-3.x, background-task

Say i want to execute a function every 5 minutes without using cron job.

What i think of doing is create a django background task which actually calls that function and at the end of that function, i again create that task with schedule = say 60*5.

this effectively puts the function in a time based loop.

I tried a few iterations, but i am getting import errors. But is it possible to do or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No It's not possible in any case as it will effectively create cyclic import problems in django. Because in tasks you will have to import that function and in the file for that function, you will have to import tasks.

So no whatever strategy you take, you are gonna land into the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I made something like. Are you looking for this?

```
import threading
import time

def worker():
    """do your stuff"""
    return

threads = list()
while (true):
    time.sleep(300)
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

Comment: Yes, this might serve the purpose, that i can also do through setting up a cron job, but i was actually curious about the creating a loop with background task

Comment: @Rohit. You are using thread, so you can use paralleling processing. I mean, you could call this loop as a thread from another function.